# C++ multiple definition of method error; learning Inheritance

Tags: c++

Hi everyone this is my first post on stack.  am learning C++ from a book "C++ programming for the absolute beginner" by Mark Lee.  I am currently learning inheritance by making a game about dragons. I know that its in good practice to make a header file for definitions and a cpp file for implementation. However, I followed what the guy wrote in the book and both defined and wrote the implementation in the same file .cpp (which i believe is still allowed in c++ correct?). Anyway after finishing it and trying to compile I get

> Multiple definition of Dragon::attack(int)

And this error appears for just about all the methods. There are no linker errors that pop up. Sorry if my explanation went on to long. here are the files. Thank you in advance and if it is at all possible can I keep the classes the way they are both definition and implementation in the same file.

> Dragon.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>

using std::string;
#define MAX(a,b) a>b? a:b

class Dragon
{
      private:
              int speed;
              string name;
              int hitPoints;
              int armor;
              int treasure;
              int clawDamage;
              int size;
      protected:
                Dragon(int theSize);
                int getArmor(){return armor;}
                 int& getHitPoints(){return hitPoints;}
                int getClawDamage(){return clawDamage;}
               int getSize() {return size;}
                virtual int attack(int targetArmor, int specialDamage);
     public:
            virtual int attack(int targetArmor)=0;
            virtual void defend(int damage)=0;
     int getTreasure(){return treasure;}
           virtual string getName(){return name;}
             int getSpeed(){return speed;}
           bool isAlive(){return hitPoints>0;}
};

 Dragon::Dragon(int theSize): size(theSize)
{
          if (size<1||size >4)
            size=3;
     clawDamage=2*size;
     speed=2*size;
     hitPoints=4*size;
     armor=size;
     treasure=1000*size;
     srand(time(0));
}
 int Dragon::attack(int targetArmor, int specialDamage)
{
        int useSpecial=rand()%2; //0 or 1
        int damage;
        if(useSpecial)
        damage=specialDamage;
         else 
         damage=getClawDamage();
         return MAX(damage-targetArmor,0);
}
```

> BlackDragon.cpp

```
#include<string>
#include"Dragon.cpp"

using std::string;

class BlackDragon : public Dragon
{
      private:
              int poisonDamage;
      public:
             BlackDragon(int theSize);
             int attack(int targetArmor);
             void defend(int damage);
             string getName(){return "Black Dragon";}
};

BlackDragon::BlackDragon(int theSize):Dragon(theSize)
{
     poisonDamage=getSize();
}
int BlackDragon::attack(int targetArmor)
{
    return Dragon::attack(targetArmor, poisonDamage);
}
void BlackDragon::defend(int damage)
{
    getHitPoints()-=damage - getArmor();
}
```

> RedDragon.cpp

```
#include<string>
#include"Dragon.cpp"

using std::string;

class RedDragon : public Dragon
 {
      private:
              int fireDamage;
      public:
             RedDragon(int theSize);
             int attack(int targetArmor);
             void defend(int damage);
             string getName(){return "Red Dragon";}
};
RedDragon::RedDragon(int theSize):Dragon(theSize)
{
            fireDamage=4*getSize();
}
int RedDragon::attack(int targetArmor)
{
    return Dragon::attack(targetArmor, fireDamage);
}
void RedDragon::defend(int damage)
{
     getHitPoints()-=(damage-getArmor())/3;
}
```

> BlueDragon.cpp

```
#include<string>
#include"Dragon.cpp"

using std::string;

class BlueDragon: public Dragon
{
      private:
              int iceDamage;
      public:
             BlueDragon(int theSize);
             int attack(int targetArmor);
             void defend(int damage);
             string getName(){return "Blue Dragon";}
};
BlueDragon::BlueDragon(int theSize):Dragon(theSize)
{
            iceDamage=3*getSize();
}

int BlueDragon::attack(int targetArmor)
{
    return Dragon::attack(targetArmor, iceDamage);
}
void BlueDragon::defend(int damage)
{
     getHitPoints()-=(damage-getArmor())/2;
}
```

> DragonLord.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
#include "Dragon.cpp"
#include "RedDragon.cpp"
#include "BlueDragon.cpp"
#include "BlackDragon.cpp"

int menuChoice();

int main(void)
{
    using std::srand;
    using std::time;
    using std::rand;
    using std::cout;
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    Dragon* dragons[3];
    int hp=15;
    int armor=2;
    int tempArmor;
    int tempAttack;
    dragons[0]=new RedDragon(rand()%4+1);
    dragons[1]=new BlackDragon(rand()%4+1);
    dragons[2]=new BlueDragon(rand()%4+1);
    Dragon* d=dragons[rand()%3];
    cout<<"Welcome noble knight. \n"
    <<"You must save a princess."
    <<"She has been captured by a "
    <<d->getName()<<"\n"
    <<"You must defeat the dragon. \n";
    cout<<"Your hit points are: "<<hp<<"\n";
   while(d->isAlive()&&hp>0)
    {
        int choice=menuChoice();
    if(choice==3)
         goto RUN;
      else if(choice==1)
      {
           tempAttack=rand()%16+5;
           tempArmor=armor;
      }
      else
      {
          tempAttack=rand()%11;
          tempArmor=armor+4;
      }
      hp-=d->attack(armor);
      d->defend(rand()%16-5);
      cout<<"\nYou deliver a mighty blow and deel "<<tempAttack
      <<" damage. \n";
      cout<<"Your hit points are: "<<hp;
      }
      if(d->isAlive())
      cout<<"\nYou have perished before"
      <<" the might of the dragon.\n";
      else 
      cout<<"\n\nYou ahve slain the dragon!"
      <<"Congratulations.\n"
      <<"the Princess is saved. \n";
      return 0;
      RUN:
          cout<<"\nYou ahve fled in cowardice.\n";
          return 0;
}

int menuChoice()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    int choice;
    do{
        cout<<"\n[1]Atack\n"
        <<"[2]Defensive Mode\n"
        <<"[3]Run Away\n";
        cin>>choice;
      }while(choice<1&& choice>3);
      return choice;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of that macro and use `std::max`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your classes in *.cpp* files and including them multiple times. For example, when you include *Dragon.cpp* in both *BlackDragon.cpp* and *BlackDragon.cpp*, there will be two definition of everything in `Dragon` class. That will cause this problem (breaks [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)).

There are ways to avoid this, but in *C++* most common and easy practice is to declare your class in *header (.h)* files and implement the methods in *.cpp* files. If one class definition is needed in another, then include the *.h* file.

You can do like this:

```
//Dragon.h
class Dragon
{
  private:
          int speed;
          string name;
          int hitPoints;
          int armor;
  /// other variables and methods
}

//Dragon.cpp
 #include"Dragon.h"


//implement methods
```

then in inheriting classes

```
//BlueDragon.h
 #include"Dragon.h"

 //BlueDragon Class definition

//BlueDragon.cpp
#include "BlueDragon.h"
//BlueDragon methods implementation
```

Comment: He has `#pragma once`.

Comment: But if I dont include the dragon class in the other classes will it still be inherited? and I do have pragma once

Comment: @user3681722, no, you have to include header files. look updated reply.

Comment: It's a bad practice to include .cpp, but it is legal, I think. But I'm not sure if `#pragma once` works with .cpp.

Comment: Thank you I will try your suggestions

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I already mentioned that .cpp files can be included, but will complicate the code base, and I don't think OP is ready for that complication. And `#pragma` only can not help here

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `#pragma once` prevents a file being included more than once in a single translation unit; it is no help with a file (with definitions in it) being included in many translation units as is happening here.

Comment: Thank you guys. as soon as I broke up the files like Hasan suggested it compiled without complications. Just out of curiosity as Cat said having .cpp class files is legal, is there a way to make my code work the way i initially posted. Because afterall the guy who wrote the book did it that way. Or should I assume he wrote it without trying to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You are including ".cpp" files. It's a very bad idea. In practice, you should define your classes in header files and implement them in cpp files. That way, you don't expose your implementation, only your interface, and each symbol will be compiled one and only one time. That should solve your problem.

Also, there are case when you may want to implement methods in header files, like when creating a template class, but you should never include anything that's not a header.

Your book seems a bit outdated, using a macro instead of std::max and such. You should probably grab a new, shiny book about C++11 instead.

Comment: Thank you, it is a bit outdated written in 2009. I got it because the way its written introduces C++ in a more fun way I get to make games and his explanations of concepts make sense to me. However, if you know any books that can teach me intermediate level programming, while explaining the concepts in a understandable way I would appreciate it :)